# doing quiz help in excel

Tags: excel

how do i make all the answers that are "correct" add up in percentage??
i have done the correct and try again....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your table looks like this (where `1` means correct and `0` incorrect):

```
   |  A
---+-----
1  |  1
2  |  1
3  |  1
4  |  0
```

You can put the following into `A10`:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A9)
```

to get the result

```
0.75
```

Comment: You could use AVERAGE instead of SUM()/COUNT().  For 0's and 1's, the Average is the same as the percent equal to 1.